# Create Array as Vector with 10 Million elements and assign random numbers without duplicates

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, vector, duplicates

I try to code myself a Table with random generated Numbers. While that is simple as it is, causing that Vector not having any duplicates isn't as easy as I thought. So far my Code looks like that:

```
QStringList generatedTable;

srand (QTime::currentTime().msec());
std::vector<int> array(10000000);
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % 10000000000)+1;
}
```

It generates numbers just fine, but because I'm generating a large amount of array elements (10 Million), even though I'm using 10 Billion possible numbers, it will create duplicates. I already browsed a bit and found something that seems handy to use, but doesn't work properly in my Program. The code is from another stackoverflow User:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<set>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    std::set<int> duplicates;

    auto it = std::remove_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [&duplicates](int i) {
        return !duplicates.insert(i).second;
    });
    size_t n = std::distance(std::begin(arr), it);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

It basically moves all the duplicates to the end of the Array, but for some reason does it not work anymore when the array gets bigger. The code will always place the iterator `n` at 32.768 as long the Array stays above a Million. Under a Million it drops *slightly* to ~31.000. So while the code is nice it doesn't really help me  alot. Does someone have a better option I could use? Since I'm still a Qt and C++ beginner do I not know how to solve that problem properly.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is store a bunch of values with no duplicates, have you looked into [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (whose whole purpose is to store a bunch of values with no dupes)?

Comment: there are duplicates (pun inteded). However, the usual solution will be difficult to apply here because you would need a container will all possible numbers, shuffle that then pick the first elements. Why do you need a container that large?

Comment: Note that `int` may not have the depth to represent 10 billion different numbers. Typical implementations stop at around 4.4 billion.

Comment: the code you posted looks a bit odd. Can you give a reference? Maybe you misunderstood what it was actually for or you missed some context

Comment: @OP *Beginner do I not know how to solve that Problem properly* -- You are trying to explain your solution, and hoping we can fix your solution.  Instead, you should first tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve.   Wanting 10 billion random numbers stored in a container sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Basically what I try to achieve is to create a Table which goes from 1 to 10 Million with assigned random Numbers up to 10 Billion. Reason for that is that I try to write a Program that can anonymise Data like Custom Numbers and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sample `N` integers without replacement from the range `[low, high)` you can write this:

```
std::vector<int> array(N);   // or reserve space for N elements up front
 
auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
    
std::ranges::sample(std::views::iota(low, high), 
                    array.begin(),
                    N, 
                    gen);

std::ranges::shuffle(array, gen);  // only if you want the samples in random order
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aGvjGG).

Note that this requires C++20, otherwise the range to be sampled from can't be generated lazily, which would require it to be stored in memory. If you want to write something similar before C++20, you can use the range-v3 library.

Comment: Hello, seems like a good Answer, but I have one Problem when I wanna try it out. I add CONFIG += c++20 to my .pro file, but Qt doesn't seem to recognize it properly. I'm using Qt Creator 4.13.2 with Qt5.15.1. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Deto24 I'm sorry, I don't really know much about how Qt works.

Comment: @Deto24 Can you clarify what you mean by `"I add CONFIG += c++20 to my .pro file, but Qt doesn't seem to recognize it properly"`?  Does your compiler support `c++20`?

Comment: @G.M. I changed between MinGW7.4, MinGW8.1 and now using MSVC2019. While MSVC19 allows me to include ```<ranges>``` does it still throw me the Error: ```C2039: "ranges" is no Member of std```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest but at the same time most efficient thing is to implement a binary search tree. Generate the random number in your range and check if it's not already there. Note that the operations are performed in a time O(n)